# Can I use TortoiseGit and SourceTree with the same project, same computer?

Tags: git, tortoisegit, atlassian-sourcetree

I like TortoiseGit and SourceTree with their own advantages and want to use **both of them at the same time, with the same project, in the same computer.**

1. I am not sure whether it will cause **conflict** when I do that?
2. If it does, **how can I avoid the conflicts** or there is no way to use
   both of them like that?

Thank you.

Comment: I often run into problems using both.  TortoiseGit seems to constantly run processes that lock git.  This will usually result in an error message that git is locked due to another process.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

TortoiseGit is based on TortoiseSVN, and is primarily meant for users familiar with that, but because of that, lacks a few features that are normal in Git. It does not, for instance, understand the concept of staging. In TortoiseGit's mind, a file is either tracked, or isn't tracked.

If you have both staged and unstaged changes to the same file, which is normal in Git and which SourceTree seemingly lets you do, TortoiseGit will complain about that, and it will not be able to handle that file until you either stage or unstage all changes. TortoiseGit can do that for you, if you let it.

Comment: @alpav No, it's not. My answer is upvoted and accepted because it answers the question that you failed to understand, and I resent your accusation of fraud. Re-read the question, re-read my answer.